# Golang heap profile and runtime.Memstats show different result

Tags: go, memory, heap-memory

here is my runtime.Memstats, it shows my HeapInuse is about 14.76GB

```
# Alloc =15850481912
# TotalAlloc = 14112784178272
# SyS =27469378624
# Lookups =0
# Mallocs = 220246619671
# Frees = 220208758959
# HeapAlloc = 15850481912
# HeapSys = 26495549440
# HeapIdle = 10622779392
# HeapInuse = 15872770048
# HeapReleased = 586293248
# HeapObjects = 37860712
# Stack = 4063232 / 4063232
# MSpan = 42770560 /213057600
# Mcache = 9600 /15600
# BuckHashsys = 2771335
# GCsys =732745144
# Othersys = 21176273
# LastGc = 1695642639886128527
```

but when i using go too pprof to check heap profile(sample_index=inuse_space),it shows that my total in use space is about 12616.97MB, which is different with Memstats.HeapInuse. I want to know why they are different and which one should i trust.

```
Showing nodes accounting for 12551.20MB, 99.48% of 12616.97MB total
Dropped 143 nodes (cum <= 63.08MB)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 14 
flat    flat%  sum%    cum     cum%
12288MB 97.39% 97.39% 12288MB 97.39% github.com/coocood/freecache.NewRingBuf (inline)
262.53MB 2.08% 99.47% 262.53MB 2.08% github.com/coocood/freecache. (*segment).expand (inline)
0.67MB 0.0053% 99.48% 12288.67MB 97.40% github.com/ coocood/ freecache . NewCacheCustomTimer
```

i try to check the memory stat from /proc/pid/stat, looks like its VmRSS is more close to Memstats.HeapInuse

```
VmPeak: 28930944 kB
VmSize: 28865408 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM : 16605472 kB
VmRSS : 16605472 kB
RssAnon:        16576956 kB
RssFile:           28504 kB
RssShmem:             12 kB
VmData: 27090500 kB
VmStk:       132 kB
VmExe:     28488 kB
VmLib:      4220 kB
VMPTE:     34552 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
```

Comment: "I want to know why they are different [...]" because "memory usage" is f.... complicated and no simple number tells "the truth". Note that pprof reports a sample. "[...] and which one should i trust." This is based on a false premise. It is not the case that one value is "more accurate" or "can be trusted more". It solely depends on what you actually try to accomplish. Tuning memory consumption is best done through pprof, no matter whether you "like" or "trust" (whatever that should mean).

Comment: @Volker I am trying to identify the cause of an OOM issue. However, according to the results provided by pprof, I am only using 12551.20MB, which is less than the system's 16GB memory. So, I would like to know if there are any other places besides the inuse_space that could consume memory

Comment: "I am only using 12551.20MB" No. Again. The idea of "memory usage" is **complicated**. If believe that you somehow "use 12551.20MB of 16GB available" then this is part of the problem. If you face OOM you _must_ reduce memory consumption but _please_ stop focusing on a single number and thinking of that as something with 7 significant digits. How much memory your application "uses" depends on what is considered "use" and your "OOM killer" might consider a totally different metric than _any_ of the various "memory usage" numbers you showed.

Comment: Heap allocations are important, but stack space "uses memory" too and you cannot ignore that one. Your application uses a shitload of memory, be it 12.6 GB, 14.8 GB or 16.6 GB. It uses _far_ too much. Do the following: Find _where_ your application uses _a lot_ of memory and reduce that. Use pprof. If pprof shows you use 30% less RAM in some code path you use 30% less, regardless if the baseline was 300M, 400M or 500M. This is a _reliable_ number. (In contrast to "memory usage" which is _not_, again: **not** a welldefined and agreed on metric.

Comment: @Volker: which of the go profile(s) would you recommend looking at to identify the code paths that "use memory" (<- not clearly defined at that point, I agree) ?

Comment: Then read https://go.dev/doc/gc-guide this should explain a bit more why "memory usage" is not a simple "my machine has 16GB RAM and my code uses 14.7 GB so it should be okay". Try tuning GOGC and GOMEMLIMIT.

Comment: There are two things: To consider: What is the "working set" of RAM your code _needs_? If you want to work on a large graph with lots of data attached to each node you better make sure you find a frugal representation (e.g. storing enums as ints instead of strings or even bitpacking stuff or deduplicating data, etc.) Use unsafe.Sizeof or https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools@v0.15.0/go/analysis/passes/fieldalignment/cmd/fieldalignment after optimizing your data representation.

Comment: The second thing are allocations (that stress GC or are simply unneeded): Use pprof to find allocations and try to get rid of them. You can use pprof too to check that step 1 (boiling down static memory consumption of your working data set) reduced consumption. The GC article is worth reading and has (pretty advanced) information and other links.

Comment: @Volker yeah,through alloc_space, I found frequent heap memory allocations along certain code paths, but they are no in the top list of inuse_space

Comment: It might be that allocations _per se_ are not your problem but the shear volume of data you want to work with at the same time. The tool here is paper, pencil, brain. You must have some understanding of how large the representation of your data you intend to work with at each moment actually is. This is not related to code but to business and architecture.

Comment: @JackyZhao: I assume you use linux,  what kernel do you use (`uname -r`) ? also: what is your go version ? on our side, we have [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/64332) which has several similarities with yours (RSS inconsistent with MemStats or memory profiles)

Comment: @LeGEC i am using centos 7.2 and golang 1.19, i think we have encountered different problem since my case has nothing to do with golang version. My problem is frequently gc cause cpu usage is high, so i use go pprof to check heap alloc_sapce instead of default inuse_space, and use sync.Pool to reduce object allocation to alleviate gc.